# MySQL — hierarchical selection

Tags: mysql

I have a `table` for my country territorial divisions, which does as follows :

- level 0: country
- level 1: district
- level 2: county
- level 3: parish

(the names were translated on Google)

This levels correspond to a `parent => child` pseudo relationship that goes as follows:

```
TABLE zones

id
parent_id
name
```

Sample data:

```
VALUES (1,0,'LEVEL 1')
VALUES (2,1,'LEVEL 2')
VALUES (3,2,'LEVEL 3')
```

So far so good. Now my problem is: how can I select all `zones` from a certain district (level 1) that are related to it?

Comment: what does it mean "related"? that lay in the same country? or all "child" counties? or parishes? or all of them? :]

Comment: Maybe that was confusing. `parent_id` is the `id` of the parent `zone`, so `LEVEL 1` is parent of `LEVEL 2` that is parent of `LEVEL 3`

Comment: At some point, there'll need to be a discussion about whether the hierarchy works in general (in the USA, 'states' have counties; in the UK, there isn't a 'district' level between 'country' and 'county').  However, that is tangential to the main question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the table is just for this country, kind of sticked to traditional values. Anyway, it could be worked out with an extra field to classify the occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all information in joined format:

```
SELECT *
FROM zones l1
INNER JOIN zones l2 ON l2.parent_id = l1.id
INNER JOIN zones l3 ON l3.parent_id = l2.id
WHERE l1.id = <id>
```

However if you want to simply list all related zones (not including the district itself, but only county and parishes of that district), you'll need to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT l2.*
FROM zones l1
INNER JOIN zones l2 ON l2.parent_id = l1.id
WHERE l1.id = <id>

UNION ALL

SELECT l3.*
FROM zones l1
INNER JOIN zones l2 ON l2.parent_id = l1.id
INNER JOIN zones l3 ON l3.parent_id = l2.id
WHERE l1.id = <id>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a fixed-depth to the hierarchy (just 4 levels) you can write the SQL fairly easily.  If the hierarchy was not fixed, you'd have to work a lot harder.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Zones
 WHERE name = 'LEVEL 1'
UNION
SELECT zc.*
  FROM Zones AS zd
  JOIN Zones AS zc ON zc.parent_id = zd.id
 WHERE zd.name = 'LEVEL 1'
UNION
SELECT zp.*
  FROM Zones AS zd
  JOIN Zones AS zc ON zc.parent_id = zd.id
  JOIN Zones AS zp ON zp.parent_id = zc.id
 WHERE zd.name = 'LEVEL 1';
```